# simple_format in Rails displays ugly html code in meta description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, metadata, meta-tags

To display an article I use the following line in the articles/show.html.haml

```
= simple_format(@article.content)
```

Viewing the result in a broswer works perfectly. Anyhow, I use the first few words as meta description for search engines, and if the first line of the article is e.g. a link it displays ugly html code in the meta description. E.g. I have one article that starts with:

```
<p> This article is about <%= link_to 'food', 'http://test.com' %> and you can ...
```

Currently I use the following code to render the meta description:

```
@content = "#{truncate(@article.content, :length => 320)}"
```

In my application.html.erb I use:

```
<meta name="description" content="<%= @content %>">
```

In the header it displays like this:

```
<meta content="<p> This article is about <%= link_to 'food', 'http://test.com' %> and you can ..." name="description">
```

How can I assure that the content is still displayed correctly in the browser and the meta description is correct, means:

"This article is about food and you can ..."

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, you can try using for example strip_tags method

```
truncate(strip_tags(@article.content), :length => 320)
```

Not tested, but it should work, more about [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags)